# Given integer n and k, split the set {x| - 2^n + 1 ≤ x ≤ 2^n} into two subsets A and B, so that |A| = |B| and $\sum_{a\in A}a^k=\sum_{b\in B}b^k$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Example:
for $n = 2$, $k = 2$, the set $\{ x | -2^2+1\leq x\leq 2^2\}$ can be split into {-1, 1, 2, 4} and {-3, -2, 0, 3}, as $(-1)^2+1^2+2^2+4^2=(-3)^2+(-2)^2+0^2+3^2$

I wonder if this problem has its own name and some related research. I would appreciate it if anyone could give some useful information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it is relevant for you to look at  the so called Prouhet Tarry Escott Problem. It is a stronger version than what you ask, namely you need all the first few power sums equal. On the other hand because of the shape of your set in the question note that the Prouhet Thue Morse sequence gives you a solution for the partition into $A,B$ such that the first $k$th powers are equal where $0\leq k\leq N-1$.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by Prouhet, M. E. Prouhet. M´emoire sur quelques relations entre les puissances des nombres. C. R.
Acad. Sci. Paris. Serie A, 33:31, 1851. A solution (in English) can be found [here, page 75.](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/book/b2.pdf)